# Native exFAT support in 5.4 kernel - issues?

Tags: filesystems, kernel, fstab, ntfs, exfat

Fresh install Ubuntu Server 20.04. `cat /proc/filesystems` shows exfat in the output. Not installed any other packages for exFAT as it should work from kernel.

Mounted 2 internal HDDs on in fstab as below

```
#INT-1TB-4K Internal HDD mount to /mnt/INT-1TB-4K
UUID=0E7E-6579 /mnt/INT-1TB-4K exfat defaults, permissions 0 0

#INT-1TB-BAK Internal HDD mount to /mnt/INT-1TB-BAK
UUID=3037-96B0 /mnt/INT-1TB-BAK exfat defaults, permissions 0 0
```

/mnt ls-all gives

```
exharris@plexserv:/mnt$ ls -all
total 520
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root   4096 Jul  2 09:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root root   4096 Jul  2 05:15 ..
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root 262144 Jul  3 03:49 INT-1TB-4K
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 262144 Jul  3 03:49 INT-1TB-BAK
```

I get permission denied errors in the terminal when trying to create files in these folders (unless I use 'sudo', of course). This is because the 'others' write bit is set to -.

When running `sudo chmod -R 777 INT-1TB-4K` from /mnt, I get no errors, but when doing ls -all again, nothing has changed.

This is causing me problems also as I have set these up as Samba shares and also cannot write to them from other machines.

I also tried sudo chmod -R o+w INT-1TB-4K - same thing happened.

What is going on? I do not want to use exfat utils and fuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exfat` behaves just like `vfat` and since it has no concept of permissions, `chown` and `chmod` both won't work.

You have to specify mount options such as `uid`, `fmask` and `dmask`, e.g.

```
defaults,noatime,nofail,uid=1000,fmask=0133,dmask=0022
```

(run `id` to find out what your ID is).

Comment: Thank you! I read man mount but it had no section on exFAT and used 'permissions' just because that's how I'd done it for NTFS.